# Inequalities for combinations of $\int f $ and $\int (1/f)$ where $m\le f\le M$ on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality

Let $f\in C[a,b]$. Assume that $\min_{[a,b]}f=m>0$ and $M=\max_{[a,b]}f$.
Which one is true?

a. $$\frac{1}{M}\int_a^bf(x)dx+m\int_a^b\frac{1}{f(x)}dx\geq 2\sqrt{\frac{m}{M}}(b-a)$$

b. $$\int_a^bf(x)dx\int\frac{1}{f(x)}dx\geq (b-a)^2$$

c. $$\int f(x)dx\int_a^b\frac{1}{f(x)}dx\leq (b-a)^2$$

For the first one 
$$\frac{1}{M}\int _a^bf(x)+m\int _a^b\frac{1}{f(x)}dx\geq {\frac{m}{M}}(b-a)+{\frac{m}{M}}(b-a)$$
 and the last two I am not getting.
How to find these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a. Note that if $x > 0$, we have ${x\over M} + {m \over x} \ge 2 \sqrt{m \over M}$ (the function is strictly convex and unbounded as $x \downarrow 0$ and $x \to \infty$, differentiate to find the minimiser).

> $\int_a^b ({f(x) \over M} + {m \over f(x)})dx \ge \int_a^b2 \sqrt{m \over M} dx$.

For b. use Cauchy-Schwarz with the functions $x \mapsto \sqrt{f(x)}$ and
$x \mapsto \sqrt{1 \over f(x)}$.

> Let $g(x) = \sqrt{f(x)}, h(x) = \sqrt{1 \over f(x)}$. Then $(\int_a^b g(x)h(x)dx )^2 \le \int_a^b g(x)^2 dx \int_a^b h^2(x) dx$.

For c. pick any non-constant $f$ that satisfies the hypotheses.

Comment: what if $x=0$ @copper.hat

Comment: We have $f(y) \ge m > 0$. (Replace $x$ in the formula above by $f(x)$ and integrate over $[a,b]$.)

Comment: I did not get that $f(y)>0$ how does this imply $x\neq 0$

Comment: Emm, why are you concerned with $x=0$? It is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: I added an explicit computation above, but try to figure it out first...

Comment: Oh thanks I got it but are u sure b is correct I am getting c to be true since by Cauchy $f.g\leq (f^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}.g^2^{\frac{1}{2}}$ @copper.hat

Comment: Yes I am. I have added the explicit computation above, but try to figure it out first...

Comment: Thanks for your answer It was of great help

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 3):

**In fact,we have this following stronger inequality:**
$$\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right)\cdot\left(\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{1}{f(x)}dx\right)\le \dfrac{(m+M)^2(b-a)^2}{4Mm}$$
**proof**  :since $
m\le f(x)\le M$
so we have
$$\dfrac{(f-M)(f-m)}{f}<0\Longrightarrow f+\dfrac{Mm}{f}\le M+m$$
so
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+Mm\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{1}{f(x)}dx\le \int_{a}^{b}(M+m)dx=(M+m)(b-a)$$
use AM-GM inequality we have
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+Mm\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{1}{f(x)}dx\ge 2\sqrt{Mm\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right)\cdot\left(\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{1}{f(x)}dx\right)}$$
so we have
$$\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right)\cdot\left(\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{1}{f(x)}dx\right)\le \dfrac{(m+M)^2(b-a)^2}{4Mm}$$

Other hand use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right)\cdot\left(\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{1}{f(x)}dx\right)\ge (b-a)^2$$

Comment: what is $n$ here?