# How to prove $\bigl(\int_a^bf(x)dx\bigr)\bigl(\int_a^b\frac{1}{f(x)}dx\bigr)\ge (b-a)^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ be a positive and continuous function. Prove that
> $\bigl(\int_a^bf(x)dx\bigr)\bigl(\int_a^b\frac{1}{f(x)}dx\bigr)\ge (b-a)^2$.

By the mean value theorem, there exist $c$ and $\zeta$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(c)(b-a)=\int_a^bf(x)dx$ and $\frac{b-a}{f(\zeta)}=\int_a^b\frac{1}{f(x)}dx$, then we have $$\Bigl(\int_a^bf(x)dx\Bigr)\Bigl(\int_a^b\frac{1}{f(x)}dx\Bigr)=\frac{f(c)}{f(\zeta)}(b-a)^2$$

If I can prove that $\frac{f(c)}{f(\zeta)}\ge 1$, then we are down. Could anyone give me some hints? Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Basically The cauchy schwarz inequality :)

Comment: see [proof of C-S](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192657/proving-the-cauchy-schwarz-integral-inequality-in-a-different-way#:~:text=We%20take%20%CE%BB%2C%CE%BC%20as,%CE%BCd%CE%B1%E2%89%A41.) in MSE

Comment: Thanks, I know how to prove it.

Comment: Wonder if a proof can be gotten from the observation that the inequality says that the average of a function times the average of its reciprocal is at least one.

Comment: @martycohen: You should get that result if you apply “harmonic mean $\le$ arithmetic mean” to the Riemann sums.

Comment: You can find a solution as part of this Q&A: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1090491/42969